Access content from Angular APP SCORM&XApi&LMS
I have some misunderstanding how LMS and SCORM all come together.
If someone could shed on light in easy way would be perfect.
I am just confused with moodle, scorm cloud and all terms LMS , im not understanding is it going to be 3rd party LMS we upload scorm zip or it is our backend server?
So the plan is this. we prepare content with Articulate export and publish as SCORM, and then what?
During selection of quizes exam results, how can I fetch all data from my Angular app?
What do I pass in my iframe? imanifest file or once uploaded to scormcloud or etc, i pass url of it?
Then I would need to play with scorm content, like get exact time video stopped, open whiteboard and draw something and save result, and also opening whiteboard pencil might be inside scorm content itself too. how this all come together?
Sorry if it is stupid question, its first time will be working with scorm and LMS and i have huge gap to put all of this together.

try out this library for simple implementation bcz scorm is little complicated:
https://github.com/jcputney/scorm-again
